# Python Get function parent attribute

Tags: python

I have a function in python that return an inner function

```
def parent_func(func):
    def decorator(a,b):
        return a + b
    return decorator
```

for simplify lets consider this code

```
def in_func ( a, b)
  return a*b

child = parent_func ( in_func)
```

Does someone know a way to get the "func" attribute of parent_func from child?

Comment: Your `decorator` doesn't actually decorate `func` with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `func` attribute only exists in the scope of the `parent_func()` function.

If you really need that value, you can expose it:

```
def parent_func(func):
    def decorator(a,b):
        return a + b

    decorator.original_function = func
    return decorator
```

Next question is, why would you want to do that?
What is the actual design problem behind this issue?

Comment: By the way the actual design problem is that parent_func is a decorator of func and I need the real function.

Comment: @Shmuel: what I wanted to say is, /why/ do you need to get the real function? What is the original problem you try to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as an attribute on `decorator` before returning it.

```
>>> def parent_func(func):
...     def decorator(a,b):
...         return a + b
...     decorator.func = func
...     return decorator
...
>>> @parent_func
... def product(a, b):
...     return a * b
...
>>> product.func
<function product at 0x000000000274BD48>
>>> product(1, 1)
2
```

---

You are slightly misusing decorators here. What is the point of writing a decorator which completely ignores the original function it is given?

Oh, I've also used the `@foo` decorator syntax, because it's cleaner. It's equivalent to what you have written, though.